# Remote Access through same Wi-fi

Tags: remote-access

I want to access a file on my computer, a friend of mine made the mistake to push the computer from the small table it was. There was a really important file I want to access but the screen is all broken and I cant see nothing.

Is there any way I can use the terminal to remotely access this file and copy it on my computer...Even though I never thought this could happen & I never gave remote access from within the computer..

Im near the computer but have no working cables right now. We're connected to the same wi-fi. The broken computer is windows, and have at my disposal a mac.

I know my username and my password.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend an external monitor, as that's easiest. If you don't have one available, here are a few options that I can think of:

- I think that Windows hosts a UNC share by default (this is your best option, after an external monitor). On a Windows computer, you would access it from Windows Explorer using "\\name-of-broken-computer\c$" and entering the credentials to the broken computer when prompted. On a Mac, you should be able to access the file share similarly using the default file explorer with the path "smb://name-of-broken-computer/c$". I don't know much about Mac, so that path might not work; Hopefully someone else here can back me up on the Mac version of the path. (This should guide you through this option: http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5884)
- Remove the HDD (hard drive) and put it in to an external enclosure. Then plug it in to your Mac and copy whatever you need.
- If you want to get a bit technical, you could try booting the computer off of a Linux flash drive to enable more compatibility with Mac. But that would get in to highly technical issues that you wouldn't be able to solve without knowledge of Linux.

Answer (score 1):

No.  Not unless Remote Access was set up before.  This, of-course, does not mean the data is not recoverable.  You might, for example, be able to attach an external monitor or worst case, pull the hard drive out and read it in another PC.